# JQuery to Check dropdown checklist using index value manually

Tags: jquery, dropdownchecklist

How to check any one option in check list using index value in Jquery :

```
for(var i in station_list)
{
    if(temp==0)
    {
        $("#obser_location_list_label_gis_div").html("Locations:");
        $("#obser_location_list_value_gis_div").html("" +
        "<select id='obser_location_gis' name='obser_location_gis' multiple='multiple'>" +
        "<option value='-1'>all</option>" + "</select>");
    }
    $("#obser_location_gis").append("<option value="+i+">"+station_list[i]+"</option>");
    temp++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you add more detail as to what you want? do you mean check a checkbox based on the index from looping through it?  i.e. start at 0 to checkboxes.count and check one of them at the number your at?

Comment: Ya based on value of i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/K4E79/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


//check 5th checkbox
$($('input[type="checkbox"]')[4]).trigger('click');


//OR using a loop:
//loop through all of your checkboxes.. 
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'), function (ind, val) {
     //check the box that has class "checkme"
    if ($(this).hasClass('checkme')) {
        $($('input[type="checkbox"]')[ind]).trigger('click');

        //you could also do: 

       /// $(this).trigger('click');
        //or
       ///  $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');

    }
});
});
```

Comment: Its working fine but I want to mention id of this dropdowncheck list  in this code ????

Comment: Hi @Parmanand can you show me the generated HTML code of the checkboxlist? I can update then.. generally you'd put the ID of the container before the inputs in the selector.. so say your checkboxes are in a div with ID "checkboxlist".. your selector would then change to `$.each($('#checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"]')` Is that what you are looking for? if not, update question with html :)

Comment: check my new question :)

Comment: $('#obser_location_gis').children('option')[j].value how to perform click trigger on this option

Comment: when you use [i] like that it transforms the object into a javascript object - so you need to JQuery wrap it again.. so your click on that object would look like this: `$($('#obser_location_gis').children('option')[j]).trigger('click');`

Comment: this is also not working...value is coming but trigger not working

Comment: ok how bout this: 
`$('#obser_location_gis option:nth-child('+j+')').trigger('click');`

Comment: here i am getting < option > but actually I need option with check boxes so is there any way to covert all those option into check box in this code becoz in UI it is dropdown check list

Comment: I need to see your HTML buddy.. can you use jsfiddle to create something we can both work on?

Comment: This is select option list $("#obser_location_list_value_gis_div").html("" +
         "<select id='obser_location_gis'  class='input_area' name='obser_location_gis' multiple='multiple'>" +
         "<option value='-1'>all</option>" +

Comment: This is check list code for same jq162("#obser_location_gis").dropdownchecklist({defaultText:'select locations', firstItemChecksAll:true , maxDropHeight: height });
    }